# Is there a target in Visual Studio 2012 that will run when the project opens?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

**tl;dr** I would like to have a command run as soon as I open a project in Visual Studio 2012. How do achieve this?

**Longer version**

To make the front-end parts of my project build automatically in Visual Studio I have specified this in my project file:

```
<PropertyGroup Label="NodeJS">
    <NodeJSPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\tools\nodejs</NodeJSPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec command="$(NodeJSPath)\npm install" />
    <Exec command="$(NodeJSPath)\npm run test" />
    <Exec command="$(NodeJSPath)\npm run build-all" />
</Target>
```

This is fine, but this means that any sass changes are not built while the project is running. So what I'd like is to have SASS be continually compiled after opening the project in Visual Studio without any of the back-enders needing to know anything about the Node process doing it all. This means I need to run `npm install` and `npm run watch-sass` on project startup.

I know Visual Studio *2015* does a `npm install` as soon as it sees `package.json` and this is basically what I want to replicate.

Comment: For 2012 is going to be tricky... For 2013 there's a task runner extension (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708) and that have been integrated into Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1):

The following targets are executed when a project opens in Visual Studio:

> ### Design-Time Target Execution
>
> Visual Studio attempts to execute targets with certain names when it loads a project. These targets include `Compile`, `ResolveAssemblyReferences`, `ResolveCOMReferences`, `GetFrameworkPaths`, and `CopyRunEnvironmentFiles`. Visual Studio runs these targets so that the compiler can be initialized to provide IntelliSense, the debugger can be initialized, and references displayed in Solution Explorer can be resolved. If these targets are not present, the project will load and build correctly but the design-time experience in Visual Studio will not be fully functional.

You may want to stick a Condition on your target to prevent it from loading on a Build server or when building the solution from the commandline:

```
<target ... condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'">
```

But it would probably be easier to upgrade to Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 to make use of the new Task Runner which is built-into Visual Studio 2015 and ships as an extension to [Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8e1b4368-4afb-467a-bc13-9650572db708). Which can [be extended to support other task runners as well](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?query=task%20runner&f%5B0%5D.Value=task%20runner&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=4).

Comment: Thanks, this seems very relevant. But if I should just call a target `Compile`, won't I overwrite the/an existing `Compile` target? And if so, how do I hook on to/or extend that target? If you think this is too out of scope I can create a new question.

Comment: You should be able to use the compiledependson property or the beforetargets attribute on your target. The process (although for another target) is explained here: http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,25443824-c7ea-4164-892a-386c7b39ddaf.aspx